# Troubles getting this value using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Troubles getting this value: `.data("blog-title")` on hover of `.avatar` in this kind of code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://somwhere.com/"  class="frame">
<img alt="" class="avatar" src="http://something.com/pong.png/>
        </a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            some script stuff
        </script>

            <div class="note">
                        <a target="_blank" class="preview" href="http://something.com/blogpost/bar"><img src="http://http://something.com/some.gif" /></a>
                <a href="#" data-blog-title="fooname" class="block">foobar</a>
            </div>
```

Have tried various parent, finds, and etcetera. Just can't solve it.

Comment: var title = $('a.block').attr("data-blog-title"); ?  I cannot test this right now

Comment: "Have tried various parent, finds, and etcetera. Just can't solve it." Where's the code where you'v tried it?

Comment: @JuanMendes Didn't feel it would add any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:-

Assuming you have multiple sections like this, you can try this way

```
$('.avatar').hover(function(){
var value = $(this)
          .closest('.frame') // Get to the parent .frame
          .siblings('.note') // look for its sibling .note
          .find('.block') //find the anchor with class.block
          .data('blog-title'); //get the value. If this attribute value is being changed dynamically after the load then you need to use .attr('data-blog-title')

});
```

otherwise just do

```
 $('.block').data('blog-title');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kNntX/

Remember to close the quotes here

```
<img alt="" class="avatar" src="http://something.com/pong.png/">
                                                              ^----------
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! All responses—albeit slightly different—approaches  worked. Accepting yours since it was most instructive. Will likely go with a slight mod: `$(this).parent().siblings()          .find('.block').data('blog-title');` or `$('.block').data('blog-title');`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work using `data`:

```
$(".avatar").hover(function(e){
    alert($('.block').data('blog-title'));
}, function() {

});
```

- [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SEzVj/1/)

http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: @user1452893 -- no problem, glad we could help :D

Answer (score 1):

This should work? ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYGZU/))

```
$(function() {
   $(".avatar").mouseover(function() {
     console.log($(".block").data('blog-title'));  
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would advise you to keep all the `<script>` tags in one location in your HTML file this improves readability and makes it easier to see what gets triggered and the order it happens in.

That being said, you probably want to do your code something like this:

Keep in mind that in your current HTML code the element that you are after is called `.block`

```
 <script>
       //wait for the document to be ready before triggering
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.avatar').hover(function(){
               var title =  $(this).next('.note').children('.block').attr("data-blog-title");
               //do something with title now that you've loaded it.
              },
           //callback
           function(){ 
             //something else on mouseout
           });
});
</script>
```

Please be aware I haven't tested this but with a little bit of debugging this should work.

Comment: This works. Thanks! Understand your comment about the script but not mine so can't modify,

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function() {
   $(".avatar").mouseenter(function() {
     var blogTitle = $(this).closest('.frame').find('.block').data('blogTitle');
     console.log(blogTitle );  
   });
});
```